# conda skeleton don't produce build.sh and bld.bat, only meta.yaml

Tags: package, conda, pypi

I am following [THIS](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html#building-a-simple-package-with-conda-skeleton-pypi) tutorial and using the same package **click** as a sanity check.

```
conda skeleton pypi click
```

is supposed to create 3 files `meta.yaml`, `build.sh` and `bld.bat` but it's only producing `meta.yaml`

I paste here my command and the output:

```
$ conda skeleton pypi click

Warning, the following versions were found for click
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.5.1
0.6
0.7
1.0
1.1
2.0
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
2.6
3.0
3.1
3.2
3.3
4.0
4.1
5.0
5.1
6.0
6.1
6.2
6.3
6.4
6.5
6.6
6.7.dev0
6.7
7.0
7.1
7.1.1
Using 7.1.1
Use --version to specify a different version.
Using url https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/ab/5d6bc3b697154018ef196f5b17d958fac3854e2efbc39ea07a284d4a6a9b/click-7.1.1.tar.gz (290 KB) for click.
Downloading click
PyPI URL:  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/ab/5d6bc3b697154018ef196f5b17d958fac3854e2efbc39ea07a284d4a6a9b/click-7.1.1.tar.gz
Unpacking click...
done
working in /tmp/tmp8cocnwh3conda_skeleton_click-7.1.1.tar.gz
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /mnt/home/aerijman/lib/miniconda3/conda-bld/skeleton_1585617586926/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    _libgcc_mutex:    0.1-conda_forge           conda-forge
    _openmp_mutex:    4.5-0_gnu                 conda-forge
    ca-certificates:  2019.11.28-hecc5488_0     conda-forge
    certifi:          2019.11.28-py37hc8dfbb8_1 conda-forge
    ld_impl_linux-64: 2.34-h53a641e_0           conda-forge
    libffi:           3.2.1-he1b5a44_1007       conda-forge
    libgcc-ng:        9.2.0-h24d8f2e_2          conda-forge
    libgomp:          9.2.0-h24d8f2e_2          conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng:     9.2.0-hdf63c60_2          conda-forge
    ncurses:          6.1-hf484d3e_1002         conda-forge
    openssl:          1.1.1e-h516909a_0         conda-forge
    pip:              20.0.2-py_2               conda-forge
    python:           3.7.6-h8356626_5_cpython  conda-forge
    python_abi:       3.7-1_cp37m               conda-forge
    pyyaml:           5.3.1-py37h8f50634_0      conda-forge
    readline:         8.0-hf8c457e_0            conda-forge
    setuptools:       46.1.3-py37hc8dfbb8_0     conda-forge
    sqlite:           3.30.1-hcee41ef_0         conda-forge
    tk:               8.6.10-hed695b0_0         conda-forge
    wheel:            0.34.2-py_1               conda-forge
    xz:               5.2.4-h516909a_1002       conda-forge
    yaml:             0.2.2-h516909a_1          conda-forge
    zlib:             1.2.11-h516909a_1006      conda-forge

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Applying patch: '/tmp/tmp8cocnwh3conda_skeleton_click-7.1.1.tar.gz/pypi-distutils.patch'
Trying to apply patch as-is
INFO:conda_build.source:Trying to apply patch as-is
INFO conda_build.source:apply_patch(598): Trying to apply patch as-is
patching file core.py
Hunk #1 succeeded at 167 with fuzz 2 (offset 1 line).
Writing recipe for click
--dirty flag and --keep-old-work not specified. Removing build/test folder after successful build/test.

INFO:conda_build.config:--dirty flag and --keep-old-work not specified. Removing build/test folder after successful build/test.

INFO conda_build.config:__exit__(803): --dirty flag and --keep-old-work not specified. Removing build/test folder after successful build/test.
```